# Reactjs and NodeJs and Https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https

i dont know how to ask the question but here is my need.
In my project i have :

1. The frontend with reactJs.
2. The backend with nodeJs, it uses https locally.

What are the steps to assure https connexion for the whole application after build ?

Comment: Usually, I have an NGINX service in front of both, frontend and backend (a reverse proxy).

Comment: And in production mode how do we proceed ?

Comment: That's in production. You can get a valid certificate from Let's encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure HTTPs connection for the whole application you need an SSL certificate. Using `Lets Encrypt` you will be able to generate an SSL Certificate for your application.

Basically, `certbot` is a tool used to automate this process, if using `NGINX` using `python3-certbot-nginx` package will help in automatically generating an SSL certificate for your domain.

Note: I have only used NGINX & Certbot to achieve the same in my projects/apps.

Since in the context of MERN/Node.js applications,

I just recently wrote a blog about `An in-depth guide to deploying your Node.js/MERN application to production using AWS with Custom Domain & SSL`

You can refer to it, the steps can be reproduced in any Ubuntu/Linux instance.

Links to Blog:

- [Medium](https://medium.com/@kaartikjagan/an-in-depth-guide-to-deploying-your-node-js-application-to-production-using-aws-with-custom-domain-1fe3b0638a75)
- [Personal Blog](https://blog.jagankaartik.com/posts/nodejs-aws-indepth-guide/)

More Ref Links:
https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cd90d1ed3c462fe3bddd11bf8953a896